# Remove 'Changes on the form will be lost' message atk4

Tags: php, atk4, agiletoolkit

I have a page with two components. One of them is a form that shows data fields from a model. The other component has a button that reloads the form with another id of the model associated.

How can I disable the warning message of unsaved changes for that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple!

```
$form->addClass("ignore_changes");
```

Comment: Yeah :) Please accept your own question when you can, because that will help future reader to find it here. This is the right answer for sure.